# Scala automatic type inference in polymorphic functions

Tags: scala

How can I make this work?  My task at hand is a little bit more complicated but it boils down to this:

```
object Z {
  class B extends Function1[Int, Int] {
    def apply(i: Int): Int = i
  }

  def compose[T <: Function1[X, X], X](fcts: List[T]): Function1[X, X] = {
    fcts.reduce(_ andThen _)
  }

  def test() = {
    val fcts = List.empty[B]

    // Unspecified type parameter X
    val composed: Function1[Int, Int] = compose[B](fcts)
  }
}
```

I don't know how to define the "compose" function to be able to receive some concrete class B and automatically infer the dependent types X

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Scala compiler does not do well when trying to infer multiple levels of type parameters like you have. Instead, it would be simpler to remove `T <: Function1[X, X]` and simply require a single type parameter that represents the argument and return type of the `Function1`.

```
def compose[A](fcts: List[Function1[A, A]]): Function1[A, A] = {
  fcts.reduce(_ andThen _)
}
```

The compiler will have a much easier time simply inferring `A`, instead of trying to figure out what with `T` and `X` are, when `X` is part of type `T`.

```
val a: Int => Int = _ + 10
val b: Int => Int = _ * 2
val c: Int => Int = _ - 3

scala> val f = compose(List(a, b, c))
f: Int => Int = scala.Function1$$Lambda$1187/930987088@531ec2ca

scala> f(2)
res1: Int = 21
```

Note that `reduce` will throw an exception for an empty list of functions.

Comment: Sure it is a solution..  Not quite what I would have liked though..  No other options using forSome or other scala tricks?  The thing is, my compose does not exactly receive a List[B] (or a list of Function1])..  it's a little bit more complicated than that..

Comment: @MichelLemay You might be able to do something different in a different case, but in this case I don't see a way around the deficiency in type inference.